# How changing the state in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to redux and trying to implement redux in my application. I have an index.js which is rendering data to the screen and I have another component App. I added 'App' function as a subscriber for phonebookreducer. I added a few console.log in App function to check wheather it is getting called after the state is updated in phonebookreducer. the function is getting called but the updated state is not rendered on the screen. but when I add render function from index.js as a subscriber then the updated state is getting rendered.

My question is I am sure that when the state of phonebookreducer changes, it is calling the App function but why the updated state is not rendered on the screen. The 'useState' from react also uses the same mechanism but when the state Changed from useState function the updated state is getting rendered.

If adding the root render function (index.js->render)as a subscriber is the only solution. then do need to rerender my whole DOM for changing a state that corresponds to a simple component?

my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

import {PBReducer} from './reducers/phonebookreducer' // redux-reducer function

const render=()=>ReactDOM.render(<App store={PBReducer}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
render()
PBReducer.subscribe(render);
```

my component App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import AddContact from './components/addContact'
import DisplayContact from './components/displayContacts'
import {PBReducer} from './reducers/phonebookreducer' // redux-reducer function

function App(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <AddContact store={props.store}/>
      <DisplayContact store={props.store}/>

      </div>
  );
}

PBReducer.subscribe(App);
export default App;
```

my phonebookreducer.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'


const reducer=(state=[],action)=>
{
if (action.type==="NEW")
    {
      return state.concat(action.data);
    }
   return state;

}

export const PBReducer=createStore(reducer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a weird trick : `PBReducer.subscribe(render)`, actually it works indeed because you're calling `ReactDOM.render` every time the state changes.

But this is not doing a state update in the React way, this is doing an initial mount each time (`ReactDOM.render` is used to make an initial mount).

So, the solution is to use `react-redux`, with the function `connect` and `mapStateToProps`.

It looks like so then :

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

function App(props) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}/> // there's one single store in a React app, so name it 'store' (it was 'PBreducer' in your question)
      <div>
        <AddContact/>
        <DisplayContact/>
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))


/* an example component connected to the store : */

import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  items: state // the prop 'item' will be available in the component, it will match the store
})

class AddContact extends React.Component {
   /* ... */
  render() {
    return (
      /* ... use this.props.items here for example ... */
    )
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AddContact) // this line makes AddContact being synced with the store
```